# Flutter row of round buttons from label list triggered all together

Tags: flutter, dart

Need this row of "Sunday,Monday, Tuesday,...Saturday" button to be onTapped independently. Anybody knows how to this? Below is my current code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WeeklyRepeat extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WeeklyRepeatState createState() => _WeeklyRepeatState();
}

class _WeeklyRepeatState extends State<WeeklyRepeat> {
  List<String> _label = [
    'S',
    'M',
    'T',
    'W',
    'T',
    'F',
    'S',
  ];

  bool pressed = false;

  _pressed() {
    setState(() {
      pressed = !pressed;
    });
  }

  Widget _buildIcon(int index) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => _pressed(),
      child: pressed
      ? Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          height: 42.0,
          width: 42.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.black87,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(21.0),
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 0.0),
          ),
          child: Text(
            '${_label[index]}',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 20.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        )
      : Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          height: 42.0,
          width: 42.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(21.0),
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black87, width: 1.0),
          ),
          child: Text(
            '${_label[index]}',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ),
  );
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: <Widget>[
    _buildIcon(0),
    _buildIcon(1),
    _buildIcon(2),
    _buildIcon(3),
    _buildIcon(4),
    _buildIcon(5),
    _buildIcon(6),
  ],
  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a parameter to your `_onPressed` method so that you know, which icon was pressed.

To reflect that in the actual widget (where you are now checking for `pressed`) you would need to change the code so that you can know wich of the icons should be checked.

You are passing the index into the `_buildIcon` method, maybe you could use that as well to keep track of which icon has been pressed.

You could add a field to your state `pressedIndex` and put the currently pressed index there and then check for that index when building the icon.